# "Scalar subquery produced more than one element" error with BigQuery Google analysis sample

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, error-handling, google-bigquery

I keep getting the error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element. I have tried putting ARRAY in front of each SELECT (which I read to do under another question) and tried to take each select line out to determine which is not working, but nothing seems to help. I am trying to uncover the last action taken by each user who never became a purchaser on their last visit. Any help is so appreciated! Here's what I got:

```
WITH
a AS

(WITH
orig AS
(SELECT\*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`),

non_buyers AS
(SELECT fullVisitorId as visitor_id,
MAX(visitNumber) as last_visit,
FROM orig
GROUP BY fullVisitorId
HAVING COUNT(totals.transactions)=0)

SELECT non_buyers.visitor_id as visitor_id,
non_buyers.last_visit as last_visit,
(SELECT MAX(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST( hits ) )  as last_hit
FROM non_buyers LEFT JOIN orig ON non_buyers.visitor_id = orig.fullVisitorID AND non_buyers.last_visit = orig.visitNumber),

orig AS
(SELECT\*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`)

SELECT (SELECT type FROM UNNEST(hits)) as type,
(SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits)) as page,
\--(SELECT product.v2ProductName FROM UNNEST(hits)) as product,--I know this line needs more work because it is repetitive.
(SELECT eventInfo.eventAction FROM UNNEST(hits)) as action,
(SELECT eventInfo.eventLabel FROM UNNEST(hits)) as label,
visitor_id,
last_visit,
last_hit
FROM a LEFT JOIN orig ON a.visitor_id = orig.fullVisitorID AND a.last_visit = orig.visitNumber AND a.last_hit = (SELECT hitNumber FROM UNNEST( hits) )
```

I am trying to get a frame with the following fields: visitor_id, last_visit, last_hit, type, page, product, action, label for each user who never purchased anything

Comment: Every subquery can only return 1 scalar value, even when you aggregate then to one, so remove every subquery till ou find the culprit and then decide limit or aggregation

Comment: Thanks @nbk, I had tried that, but still couldnt make it work. In some way, moving the unnest to the subtable worked.

Comment: your code is unreadable and with out tabes and data nobofy can help, but you seem to have solved it yourself#

Answer (score 0):

...I figured that immediately after caving in and posting the question (after working on the problem for 6+ hours) I would figure it out. Here is the answer for anyone else who may be interested. Nonetheless, if anyone has any ideas of how to simplify the code, i'm all ears.:

```
WITH 
a AS

(WITH 
orig AS
(SELECT*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`), 

non_buyers AS
(SELECT fullVisitorId as visitor_id,
MAX(visitNumber) as last_visit,
FROM orig
GROUP BY fullVisitorId
HAVING COUNT(totals.transactions)=0)

SELECT non_buyers.visitor_id as visitor_id,
non_buyers.last_visit as last_visit,
(SELECT MAX(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST( hits ) )  as last_hit
FROM non_buyers LEFT JOIN orig ON non_buyers.visitor_id = orig.fullVisitorID AND non_buyers.last_visit = orig.visitNumber),

orig AS
(SELECT*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`, unnest(hits)) 

SELECT type,
page.pagePath,
--(SELECT product.v2ProductName FROM UNNEST(hits)),
eventInfo.eventAction,
eventInfo.eventLabel,
visitor_id,
last_visit,
last_hit 
FROM a LEFT JOIN orig ON a.visitor_id = orig.fullVisitorID AND a.last_visit = orig.visitNumber AND a.last_hit = orig.hitNumber
```